# Grails Plugin Searchable - default wildcard search

Tags: grails, searchable, grails-searchable

Is there a way to automatically wrap all searches with a wildcard?

e.g.:

```
 Book.search("*${params.q}*", params)
```

Comment: Can you try it in the UrlMapping (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings) using the Arbitrary Variables?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with .search (are you using a plugin?). However, for a wildcard search in models, I typically create a method inside the domain model class. In your example,

In the Book model class:

```
class Book {
   String title
   String author
   int year

   static List wildSearch(par, val) {
      def foundList = this.executeQuery("select b FROM Book b WHERE ${par} like \'%${val}%\'")
      return foundList
   }
}
```

In your controller:

```
def searchBook = {
   def b1 = new Book(title: "Farewell To Arms", author: "Ernest Hemingway").save()
   def b2 = new Book(title: "The Brother's Karamazov", author: "Anton Chekov").save()
   def b3 = new Book(title: "Brothers in Arms", author: "Cherry Dalton").save()

   // If you search for "Arms", This returns b1 and b3 
   def found = Book.wildSearch("title", params.title)
}
```

Example URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/mytest/mycontroller/searchBooks?title=Arms
```

Comment: Searchable is a grails plugin that makes searching a little easier.   Thanks for the suggestion but I would like to find out if there is a way to default the plugin.

Comment: Should have read your question title more closely. Sorry about that.